# Is the Bolzano-Weistrass theorem the same as as the Extreme Value Theorem?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I know the theorems do not state exactly the same thing, but, are they stating the same thing in general?

**BW Theorem: A bounded sequence of real numbers has a convergent subsequence.**

**EV Theorem: In calculus, the extreme value theorem states that if a real-valued function $f$ is continuous in the closed and bounded interval $[a,b]$, then $f$ must attain a maximum and a minimum, each at least once.**

Comment: They are different but for the real numbers a consequence of each other

Comment: @marwalix Thanks a lot, that's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both theorems need the completeness axiom of the reals. They also provide an existence for a limit of a certain Cauchy sequence. So they will be equivalent to the completeness axiom.